# Absolutely NONE of my terminal commands are working: cd, ls, nano, pry, flutter, python3… Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, macos-catalina

I can't think of what's recently changed, besides perhaps updating to a new version of Mac OS Catalina (10.15.2). All of these commands have been working for me up until today. First it was pry that stopped working, but everything else was fine. Now, they've all stopped working!

Has anyone encountered/solved a similar issue?

Comment: What is the actual error message when you execute `cd`, `ls` and `/bin/ls`?

Comment: It was just command not found. I believe I messed up my terminal path, so I just restored a backup and everything worked again

Answer (score 0):

Go execte commands, your OS looks in a variable called PATH. It contains all the different **paths** for bash scripts. Ie. cd might be in usr/bin. If no commands work then your PATH is probably corrupted. You would likely have to rewrite the entire variable so instead i suggest you google an unmodified **mac** path and copy it to your /etc/paths.

Note that i am not a native OS X user so i might be wrong with the locations of things the idea stays the same.